# Priving that the degree of an irreducible nondegenerate subvariety of $\mathbb{P^n}$ satisfies $d\ge n-k+1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

I'm reading through Dolgachev's "Classical algebraic geometry" and theorem 8.1.1 states the following
[image]

The references are not very precise, do you happen to know where, precisely, I can find the proof in any source?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One source is *On Varieties of Minimal Degree* by Eisenbud and Harris. This is available [here](https://www.msri.org/%7Ede/papers/pdfs/1987-001.pdf) at MSRI's website, for instance. The bibliography lists previous proofs by Bertini (1907), Harris (1981), and Xambo (1981), if you're looking for other sources.